# Doctrine2 - How to setup a query by months?

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, twig

Some quick context I am creating a blog archive based on month/year in the sidebar. I'm at the point where I need to show the posts for that month. I need some help in creating this query to pass onto twig.

Below is the link to the original question and what I have thus far for the setup, the query is obviously not correct (as to the nature of this post) and could use some help fleshing this out.

Help would be appreciated on showing me how to finish off these last steps with creating the proper query for posts in a month and linking it to twig.

[Symfony2 - Setting up a blog archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738550/symfony2-setting-up-a-blog-archive)

Thus far this is what I have.

**Query ( NEED HELP WITH THIS PART - HOW TO SETUP QUERY TO RETRIEVE POSTS BY MONTH/YEAR)**

```
public function getPostsByMonth($year, $month)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->from('Blog', 'b')
        ->select('b')
    ->where('created BETWEEN :june AND :july')
        ->setParameter('june', $june->format('2013-June'))
        ->setParameter('july', $july->format('2013-July'))
        ???
}
```

**Route**

```
general_sym_project_archive:
 path:  /archive/{year}/{month}
 defaults: { _controller: GeneralSymProjectBundle:Blog:archive }
```

**Controller**

```
public function archiveAction($year, $month)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $blogs = $em->getRepository('GeneralSymProjectBundle:Blog')
        ->getPostsByMonth($year, $month);

    if (!$blogs) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find blog posts');
    }

    foreach ($blogs as $post) {
        $year = $post->getCreated()->format('Y');
        $month = $post->getCreated()->format('F');
        $blogPosts[$year][$month][] = $post;
    }



    return $this->render('GeneralSymProjectBundle:Default:archive.html.twig', array(
        'blogPosts' => $blogPosts,
    ));
```

**Twig** (need to link posts by month to this twig)

```
<h4>Archives</h4>
                    <ol class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="{{ path('general_sym_project_archive', { 'year': '2013', 'month': '07'}) }}">July 2013</a></li>
                    </ol>
```

Comment: where are `$june` and `$july` defined ?

Comment: It's not defined it's just what I was experimenting with... any help?

Comment: What is your problem? What are the errors which block you?

Comment: The problem is not exactly knowing how to setup the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `created` field is a date time and you want to get the posts for a given month in a given year, this should work:

```
public function getPostsByMonth($year, $month)
{
    $date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01");

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
    $query = $qb
        ->where('b.created BETWEEN :start AND :end')
        ->setParameter('start', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->setParameter('end', $date->format('Y-m-t'))
    ;
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: What is the -01 for on the $date variable? Do I need to change my route to include this and for the controller? Using this as is I get the following: (ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for General\SymProjectBundle\Entity\Repository\BlogRepository::getPostsByMonth(), called in /var/www/html/SymProject/src/General/SymProjectBundle/Controller/BlogController.php on line 127 and defined in /var/www/html/SymProject/src/General/SymProjectBundle/Entity/Repository/BlogRepository.php line 29)

Comment: The '-01' is setting the DateTime object to the first day of the month.  Your error suggests you aren't passing arguments to the call to `getPostsByMonth()`, ie the $year and $month.

Comment: Hmm I've updated the controller to use getPostsByMonth() instead of getLatestBlogs(). Which loads the page fine, yet when I click on a month which has a year and month assigned it throws the error? (<li><a href="{{ path('general_sym_project_archive', { 'year': '2013', 'month': 'July'}) }}">July 2013</a></li>)

Comment: Do I need to assign the $year and $month to null inside the controller?

Comment: Ah, you'll have to convert the format of those to 'm'.  If you want the urls to have 'F' in them, you'll have to do something like this in the controller before you call that function:
`
$date = new \DateTime("{$month} 01, {$year}");
$month = $date->format('m');`

Comment: and based on your code in your question, pass them into the `getPostsByMonth()` call like …->getPostsByMonth($year, $month)

Comment: I'll have to take more time and study this. How do I make this work with your query, what changes do I need to make in my controller? I don't have to use 'F' etc.

Comment: You can change 'July' to '07' in your view and it should work directly with the `getPostsByMonth($year, $month)`.  Also, make sure to pass $year and $month to the call on line {5} of your controller. Edit: the call to `path` in your view that is

Comment: Ok, I tried that, changed the twig archive link from July to 07, included in ($year, $month) when calling the method in the controller. And now have this when clicking on the date - ([Semantical Error] line 0, col 54 near 'Blog b WHERE': Error: Class 'Blog' is not defined.) Everything else is left as is, did I need to make changes to the foreach loop?

Comment: Made changes to the code above to reflect exactly what I have currently.

Comment: You probably need to change 'Blog' to 'GeneralSymProjectBundle:Blog' or whatever bundle the entity is in.

Comment: Right tried that and get this - ([Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near 'b WHERE created': Error: 'b' is already defined.)

Comment: Right now that leads back to the original error: (ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(), called in /var/www/html/SymProject/src/General/SymProjectBundle/Entity/Repository/BlogRepository.php on line 44 and defined in /var/www/html/SymProject/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php line 81)

Comment: edited again to be more like how I've used the query builder.  note that the query builder and query are stored in separate variables.

Comment: and `created` needs 'b.' before it

Comment: Just tried your new solution and put in ('b') for createQueryBuilder and have the following: ([Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near 'b WHERE b.created': Error: 'b' is already defined.)

Comment: try `var_dump($query->getSql());` before the `return` and see what that says

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::getSQL() in /var/www/html/SymProject/src/General/SymProjectBundle/Entity/Repository/BlogRepository.php line 52

Comment: note the case.  It'd probably be better to do `getDql()` though, thinking about it, because it may error trying to create the sql

Comment: Performing a var_dump on getDql() displays: string 'SELECT b FROM General\SymProjectBundle\Entity\Blog b, GeneralSymProjectBundle:Blog b WHERE b.created BETWEEN :start AND :end' (length=124). then the error: ([Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near 'b WHERE b.created': Error: 'b' is already defined.)

Comment: ah, I get it, you're using the `createQueryBuilder` of the `EntityRepository`.  I've never used that before.  That automatically adds the `select()` and `from` calls, so remove those from your code (see edited answer)

Comment: Figured it out, it WORKS! Thank you tobymackenzie for your knowledge and PATIENCE, you've been a great help and I've learned from this!

Comment: Ok may have jumped the gun, just to test with 2 posts in the same month, the 2nd post in the month doesn't come up in the query? Do I need to return as an array?

Comment: Odd---for some reason it doesn't like any posts on the the 31st, I set this back manually to the 30th and it appears? Is there something missing in the query to account for the last day of the month? ($date->modify('last day of this month')?

Comment: The date modifier seems to work properly for me locally.  I can't figure out if Doctrine's `BETWEEN` is inclusive (without being able to test at the moment).  You could try changing to `->where('b.created >= :start')->andWhere('b.created <= :end')`.  I'll change my answer if that works.

Comment: Just tried this suggestion and no, it doesn't work, the last day of the month doesn't get pulled from the query.

Comment: Try the edited version of the end date.  I wasn't aware of the 't' format, but it oughta work