# doctrine query returning array, not object as expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a small project with Symfony 2.6.  Its very simple with only one entity class which maps to data inserted into a MySQL database using python running on a Raspberry Pi.

**Problem**

when I run this simple repository query the result set is seemingly being converted to an array which is causing the an error (below).  I'm not sure why this conversion is happening.

**Repo method**

```
public function getDataInRange( \DateTime $from, \DateTime $until)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        select d
        from AppBundle:weatherdata d
        where d.idx > :f
        and d.idx < :u ')->setParameters(array( 'f' => $from, 'u' => $until      ));

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

**Error**

`Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

**Database structure**

the main primary key, 'idx' is a `datetime` object, everything else is `double`.

**Have tried..**

I've tried altering the repo method to return `getArrayResult()` instead, which stops the error, but I need the result set to be in object format because of other messing about that I need to do to the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

1. U better use BETWEEN
2. Convert the DateTime to a string

   $qb->where('e.fecha BETWEEN :monday AND :sunday')
   ->setParameter('monday', $monday->format('Y-m-d'))
   ->setParameter('sunday', $sunday->format('Y-m-d'));

[please use the search, already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553183/select-entries-between-dates-in-doctrine-2)

Comment: Thats not what I'm asking. The query works fine, just returns an array set, not an object set.  And yes,  I did use search, but there are no solutions posted that have answered exactly right.